# Mouse scrolling for a Rich Text Box after disabling

Tags: c#, richtextbox

In c#,How can i make a mouse scroll at rich text box for looking the entire text if i make it as

```
  enabled=false
```

Comment: Maybe it is possible not to disable it, but make readonly?

Comment: Can you post a little more code, maybe what you have for your text box? More context helps as well.

Comment: Can you please explain a little more in detail your question? I'm not really getting what your problem is.

Comment: yeah how can i make it read only without disabling?  Oleksandr Pshenychnyy

Comment: check this http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?412971-Disabling-smooth-scroll-in-a-RichTextBox-%28RTB%29

Comment: i have a rich text box and i want that to make readonly.in that process i disabled it by making its enable property as false.What my problem is,i can read only half of the text in richtext box.its not allowing me scroll down.---------Nahuel I

Comment: set `IsReadOnly` property to `True` to make it readonly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, RichTextBox contains a property "IsReadOnly".

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.isreadonly(v=vs.95).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.isreadonly%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Use that property on the event you need to capture.